# threejs how to remove wireframe with WireframeHelper

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a function to add wireframe for the objects, so I am using the following function to do it, on the first condition it is working and I can apply wireframe

```
 function wireframe(state){
                        
                    
                      if(state=='on')
                      {
                          var wfh = new THREE.WireframeHelper( mesh, 0xf00e0e );
                          wfh.material.wireframe = true;
                          //wfh.material.linewidth = 1; // looks much better if your PC will support it
                          scene.add( wfh );                     
        
                      }
                      if(state=='off')
                      {
                           var wfh1 = new THREE.WireframeHelper( mesh,0xf00e0e );
                           wfh1.material.wireframe = false;
                           scene.remove(wfh1);  
                      }
                
            }
```

In the second condition I want to remove the applied wireframe on object, so remove the scene with `scene.remove(wfh1);`, but it doesn't work. Wireframes are not removed from the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. You need a global variable to store the wireframe object assign a value to it just once (if statement) and then selectively add it or remove it from the scene.

```
var wfh;

function wireframe (state) {

    if  ( state=='on' )
    {
        if ( wfh === `undefined` )    // so you dont add a new wfh each time you call wireframe
            wfh = new THREE.WireframeHelper( mesh, 0xf00e0e );

        scene.add( wfh );                     
    }
    else if ( state=='off' )
    {
        scene.remove( wfh );  
    }
}
```

Comment: you sir, you really awesome, i tried it full day but no luck, thanks lot for your help, and  `wfh.material.linewidth = 1;` is not working at all, do u know the reason ??

Comment: Looking at the src/extras/helpers/WireframeHelper.js code wfh does not have a material attribute.

Comment: Hi is it possible to remove the wireframe helper which is added with the scene mesh traverse ??

Comment: it is working fine without the `traverse`, as you said now i can apply WireframeHelper for the entire object with the traverse, but after that `scene.remove( wfh );`  is not working, because of that the wireframe helper is applied with the traverse, i tried to remove the whf same with the traverse that is also not working, have any idea??

Comment: my traverse is like `scene.traverse ( function (child) { if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {  wfh = new THREE.WireframeHelper( child,0xffffff ); scene.add( wfh );   } });`