# get back to normal after the traverse in threejs

Tags: three.js

in threejs am working around with the traverse method to apply the WireframeHelper for the models that is loaded using OBJMTLLoder, for this kind of models we must use traverse to apply the Wireframe for child of the Object, so here i can apply the wireframes and so on using traverse but after the traverse i can't get back to my normal object meaning that i can't remove the wireframes with the traversed mesh, the mesh is added with the scene with `scene.add( wfh );` where wfh is `WireframeHelper` , but if i use `scene.remove( wfh );` to remove the meshed WireframeHelper it doesn't work

i need to know that after the traverse we can get back to normal ?? in most cases am using traverse to make changes on my model:

Here is the code:

```
scene.traverse ( function (child)
{
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
    {
        wfh = new THREE.WireframeHelper( child, 0xffffff );
        scene.add( wfh );  
    }
});
```

updated code:

```
globalObject.traverse ( function (child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
        {
        wfh = new THREE.WireframeHelper( child,whfcolor );
        wfh.name = "wireframe_helper";

        wfh.material.opacity = 0.2;
        wfh.material.transparent = true;
        globalObject.add( wfh );

        }

     });
```

here `globalObject` is global variable assigned to `Object` now i can see the `wireframe_helper` on the child of the Object and can remove the wireframe by following code

```
globalObject.traverse( function ( child ) {

  if (child instanceof THREE.Object3D)
  {
      //alert(child.name);
      if ( child.name && child.name === "wireframe_helper" && child.material ) {

          //alert('hi');male-02-1noCullingID_male-02-1noCulling.JP

              globalObject.remove( child );

               //child.material.wireframe = true;

          }
  }
});
```

after removed the wireframe still wireframe is remains some part of the Object any clue on this ?? and am getting

```
TypeError: this.children[i] is undefined
this.children[ i ].traverse( callback );
```

on line three.js 7885

Comment: As I have said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407374/threejs-how-to-remove-wireframe-with-wireframehelper you do not need to use the `traverse()` method along with the `WireframeHelper()`.

Comment: yes Mr.@gaitat i tried `WireframeHelper()` along with the traverse, so the wireframe is applied to entire each child of the object, there is no problem about it, but i can't remove the `WireframeHelper()` if we use `traverse` , without the traverse wireframe is not working with the OBJ model alone, it is not working with the OBJMTL model, you can see the demo here http://3dmodelviewer.osiztechnologies.com/threejs/examples/envmap_reflection.html

Comment: my question is not only about the `WireframeHelper()` is it is possible to get back to normal after the traverse ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WireframeHelper()` creates an object that is added to the scene-graph. When you are using the helper inside a `traverse()` operation you are adding many objects to the scene. So if you want to remove them, you have to save them off to a variable (array in this case since you have many of them). So something like this should work:

First name the helper inside the first traverse():

```
wfh = new ...
wfh.name = "wireframe_helper";
scene.add( wfh );
```

then you should be able to do:

```
scene.traverse ( function (child)
{
    if (child.name === "wireframe_helper")
    {
        scene.remove( child );
    }
}
```

The code above would probably crash when trying to traverse a child that has been removed. 
Here is updated code:

```
to_remove = [];
scene.traverse ( function (child)
{
    if (child.name === "wireframe_helper")
        to_remove.push( child );
}
for (var i = 0; i < to_remove.length(); i++)
    scene.remove( to_remove[i] );
```

Comment: not working @gaitat, if i console the child i can't see any variables like `wfh` with the stored wireframe properties

Comment: Why `wfh` array is not added to the `scene` ??

Comment: Hi @gaitat do you have any clue on my updated code??

Comment: OK lets see, does the array `to_remove` have values after the traverse? What is its `length()`?

Comment: am used `globalObject`  instead of scene, because in my `traverse` am used `globalObject`, and it worked like a charm