# Three.js - Reload Scene from start

Tags: javascript, three.js, scene

I'm creating some kind of Visual Editor: I'm adding/deleting/transforming objects.

My initial scene only has a plane as floor (5000x5000).

I want to be able to "reload" the scene from start, that is to say to remove everything except the floor by clicking on the button "New".

How could it be possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could traverse the scene object, check what objects you have there and then remove them. If there are some Meshes you want to keep, set an attribute or name on them and check also for that name.

The following Example function `clearScene()` removes on call all Meshes from the scene that have the `keepMe`-**attribute** set to **false** or **dont have one** at all:

```
floor = new THREE.Mesh( /* ...  */ );
floor.userData = { keepMe: true };

// ...

function clearScene() {
    var to_remove = [];

    scene.traverse ( function( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh && !child.userData.keepMe === true ) {
            to_remove.push( child );
         }
    } );

    for ( var i = 0; i < to_remove.length; i++ ) {
        scene.remove( to_remove[i] );
    }
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/138/

Removal-bugfix based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24678437/4977165) by @gaitat

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't remove all meshes. It deletes some of them. :/

Comment: It deletes only the first, third, fifth...
And I get this error message:
`TypeError: b[c] is undefined
 
...b=this.children,c=0,d=b.length;c<d;c++)b[c].traverse(a)},traverseVisible:functio...`

Comment: Ops, my testcase was not complex enough, i will check this :-)

Comment: No problem, I'm very thankfull that you're helping me :)

Comment: Updated with a fix! Also noticed that when cloning a mesh the ```userData``` also gets cloned and recognized as an ```ownProperty```, just in case your usecase involves cloning.

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you very much :D
Do you know how it could delete my colladas too? :s

Comment: Get the ```collada.type``` and add another check: ```else if ( child instanceof <collada type> === true ) { /* */ }```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92979/discussion-between-falk-thiele-and-srcbh).